# How can I get exact Facebook like count?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I have Facebook like button on my website, created as following:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2fexample.com&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&width=110&action=like&colorscheme=light&height=35"
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
  allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

Like count at the moment is displayed as `1,5 k`. I would like to get exact number of likes.

I have tried to query `http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com`, but response I am getting is:

```
{
   "id": "http://example.com",
   "shares": 349
}
```

I have also tried to use FQL:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT 
                                  like_count,total_count,click_count,commentsbox_count
                                FROM link_stat
                                WHERE url='http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com'
```

And response is:

```
{
   "data": [
     {
       "like_count": 251,
       "total_count": 349,
       "click_count": 0,
       "commentsbox_count": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get exact count number?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting 1.5k? Can you give link and screenshots of it?

Answer (score 1):

The exact like count is the total_count you see there.
For some reason Facebook counts comments and shares as a like with its like button.

Don't forget that http://example.com is different than https://example.com and http://www.example.com/
Make sure you add up all those aliasses.